# How do I convert a mobile phone GPS to x,y,z with origin at the center of the Earth?

Tags: 3d, gps, wgs84

I need to accurately visualize points coming from iPhone (and other) GPS data in 3D.

So, what I'd like is to take a WGS84 (right?) point and transform that into an X,Y,Z vector with the origin at the center of the Earth.

I Googled for GPS/WGS84 to 3D but I think my search terms are not so great

Does someone have a pointer for where to start?

In future, I'll also need to take elevation information into account if available, but that isn't so important immediately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what your looking for is representing your data in ECEF (Earth Centered Earth Fixed) notation.

Some good [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) stuff

Comment: And here I was hoping we'd get an answer which included specifying the location of Earth within the universe :P

Answer (score 0):

Latitude and longitude are relatively easy, since they're just angles, however altitude is a bit tricky because the Earth isn't exactly round. If you don't need very great accuracy, [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions) has formulas for converting from a spherical coordinate system into a cartesian one. Be warned that this is not quite accurate because the Earth resembles an ellipsoid more than a perfect sphere.

Comment: ECEF uses the ellipsoid model...see my answer if you need that much precision.

Comment: @paquetp: Oh, on second look, the article actually had links to some formulas at the bottom. Didn't notice that at first.

Comment: Ah glad you discussed that.  I was thinking it probably wasn't as easy as simple polar to cartesian.